# Is it possible to create an instance method object based on the associate class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Prior to construct an instance of class Foo, I would like to create an instance method object of a method defined in class Foo and assign it to a variable. I would then create an instance of class Foo, and execute the instance method object via the variable against the newly created instance. Is this doable? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Eh? Sorry, I am having a real hard time parsing your question. Is there any way you could phrase it differently? Perhaps illustrate it with an example?

Comment: Congratulations, you've set a new record! *Four* *different* interpretations of your question resulting in as many answers! I count one classmethod, one bound method alias, one unbound method reference and one stand-alone function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Not quite 4.  the answer posted by larsmans and myself are pretty much identical (and posted within approximately 3 seconds of each other) ... speaking of which, I think I'll delete mine ... (so I guess that makes only *3 different interpretations*...Not sure if that keeps it from being a record breaker though ;)

Comment: @mgilson: quick, make yours a class method! :-P

Comment: There recently was this question that more or less asked for the definition of *abstraction*, so I think the record is safe. It is interesting to note that all the answers are hedged with the phrase "something like this".

Comment: I think the question is clear enough and that @larsmans has answered it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Your are right. I should have provided an example to go with my question. I shall watch out for that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly that you want something like this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, msg):
...         self.msg = msg
...     def speak(self):
...         print(self.msg)
...      
>>> tell_me = Foo.speak
>>> tell_me(Foo("hello!"))
hello!
```

Yes, this is possible. `Foo.speak` is an unbound method, which is a callable (function) that can be passed an instance as its first argument to obtain the same behavior that you'd get from a bound method such as `Foo("hello").speak`.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining it ...

Comment: @larsmans - Your answer is exactly what I am looking. Thanks for comprehending my question and sorry for not making my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = self.f

    def f(self):
        print "foo"

foo = Foo()
foo.g()
```

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, instance methods are just functions that are convenient to call and pass `self` as the first parameter. You should be able to do something like this:

```
def bar(self):
    pass

class Foo(object):
   pass

x = bar
f = Foo()
bar(f)
```